# C# delay in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I use 2 `Parallel.ForEach` nested loops to retrieve information quickly from a url. This is the code:

```
while (searches.Count > 0)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(searches, (search, loopState) =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(search.items, item =>
                {
                    RetrieveInfo(item);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

The outer `ForEach` has a list of, for example 10, whilst the inner `ForEach` has a list of 5. This means that I'm going to query the url 50 times, however I query it 5 times simultaneously (inner `ForEach`).

I need to add a delay for the inner loop so that after it queries the url, it waits for x seconds - the time taken for the inner loop to complete the 5 requests.

Using `Thread.Sleep` is not a good idea because it will block the complete thread and possibly the other parallel tasks.

Is there an alternative that might work?

Comment: This is scary. Can you explain what you mean by delay? You want the inner loops to wait before returning to the outer? You realise they're parallel yes? If that's what you want.. make them synchronous..

Comment: Do I understand it right, that the 5 in the inner loop are just an example and no related to the 5 simultaneous requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my understanding, you have 50 tasks and you wish to process 5 of them at a time.

If so, you should look into ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to process 50 tasks with a maximum degree of parallelism at 5.  When one task stops, another task is permitted to start.

If you wish to have tasks processed in chunks of five, followed by another chunk of five (as in, you wish to process chunks in serial), then you would want code similar to

```
for(...)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(
      [paralleloptions,]
      set of 5, action
   )
}
```

Comment: Now I'm also keeping track of the time taken for each inner loop, and after the outer loop completes, I take the time taken of the quickest inner loop and wait accordingly using Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Ho w can we add delay to each task ? Meaning, if we are executing 5 tasks at a time them how we can add a delay of 1sec for each so that each task is executing after 1 sec of the previous one.